# WYGWAM font and size menus after upgrade to 3.0.2

Tags: pixelandtonic, wygwam, size, toolbar

Just upgraded to Wygwam 3.0.2  (EE 2.6.1)

The font and size menus are no longer available in the main toolbar, and though I see options for them in the advanced configuration options, they aren't appearing for me even when I've chosen them either. (I've set fontSize_sizes, fontSize_defaultLabel, font_names and font_defaultLabel)

I'd like to know how to get them to appear again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct from the [blog post announcing WYGWAM 3](http://pixelandtonic.com/blog/wygwam-3)

> We’ve made some executive decisions on that last point: in Wygwam 3 you no longer have the option to customize font styles directly from the editor or add emoticons. If you have an issue with that, you’re probably using the wrong CMS to begin with.